# improving (Yii) caching system to get the best service to visitors

Tags: php, caching, yii

I have a Yii 1.1.14 application with a very heavy db (a user-built-db costantly growing). I've spend last 30 days to improve queries and performances and I'm satisfied about that.

However, there are some complex queries need in some circustances about 10 seconds or even more to get data. Of course, when I get results I cache them for the time I think is opportune (from 4 hours to 48 hours) and for this period visitors don't have to wait.

Question: I would to offer the best service to my visitors, avoid to make them waiting time to get page. What do you recommend as solution? What about cron job? And what about AJAX call to update cache data to call when page is complete?

Thanks

Comment: There are several possibilities, do the request via AJAX as you said and add some form of loading indicator, or add it to a server queue that gets processed by a dedicated background service. Try to implement it and ask again if you encounter any problems, this time with code.

Comment: I would some opionion before start. Anyone have implemented anything like that? Or anything different could solve my question?